# Find the additive inverse of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vector-fields

[Exercise with proposed solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjUXA.png)

So for this question, the functions I am getting for the additive inverse are the following:

-u
and
-6-u

following the process of the answer in the following question:

[Finding the additive inverse in a vector space with unusual operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671696/finding-the-additive-inverse-in-a-vector-space-with-unusual-operations)

Which will give me -3 and -3 for the vector.

For some reason it is still wrong.

I think I am misunderstanding something

Update:
(u1,u2) element of V, (v1,v2) element of V: Addition is defined as (u1+v1-3, u2+v2+3) and not as simply (u1+v1, u2+v2). So I can't just say that the additive inverse is -(u2,u2).
If I set u1+v1-3=3 and u2+v2+3=-3, I get v1=-u1 and v2 = -6-u2 which would represent the i functions as mentioned above. However, they don't seem to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $(u,v)=-(x,y)$ is the additive inverse of $(x,y)$ then we must have $(x,y)+(u,v)=0_V$ I'm getting $$-(x,y)=(-x+6,-y-6)$$

Comment: (u1,u2) element of V, (v1,v2) element of V: Addition is defined as  (u1+v1-3, u2+v2+3) and not as simply (u1+v1, u2+v2). So I can't just say that the additive inverse is -(u2,u2). So your solution didn't work because of that.

Comment: If I set u1+v1-3=3 and u2+v2+3=-3, I get v1=-u1 and v2 = -6-u2 which would represent the i functions as mentioned above. However, they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first several are correct but you seem to have misunderstood the last question.  You are asked for the additive inverse of (x, y) which will depend on x and y, not constants.  (x, y)+ (p, q) is defined as (x+ p- 3, y+ q+ 3).  Since the additive identity is (3, -3) we must have x+ P- 3= 3 and y+ q+ 3= -3 so p= 6- x and q= -y- 6.

The additive inverse of (x, y) is (6- x, -y- 6).

Comment: I dont thinkI actually misunderstood it. I just made an algebra mistake tbh. However, your solution does not work for some reason. It gives me (3, -3) for the additive inverse which is set as wrong on webwork.

Comment: Nevermind. I did misunderstand something. The whole thing that confused me was that I thought I have to put in an absolute number. Your solution worked. Thank you sir.